# CRON Job file issue

Tags: cron, cpanel

i have problems with Cron jobs, it's always said "No such file or directory"

I tried everything but it's still not working on that cPanel.

```
-q /home/user/tracker.domain.com/cron/3.php
```

It's using subdomain who is not in public_html.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the full php binary path inside the cronjob. Assuming your php binary full path is `/usr/bin/php` then your cronjob will look like this:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/user/tracker.domain.com/cron/3.php
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use php before -q in your cron jobs like this

php -q /home/user/tracker.domain.com/cron/3.php